# How to rewrite a Magento Block with an extension?

Tags: magento

I want to rewrite the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View block.

I created this file: config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <JB_CustomPrice>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </JB_CustomPrice>
  </modules>
  <global>

<blocks>
      <customprice>
        <class>JB_CustomPrice_Block</class>
      </customprice>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product_view>JB_CustomPrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
</blocks>
</config>
```

Then I created the block in
/app/code/local/JB/CustomPrice/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php

```
<?php
class JB_CustomPrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
   public function getJsonConfig()
   {
      return 'test';
   }
}
?>
```

Though, the product view doesn't change, even not when I call the getProduct() method. What's going wrong?

Comment: You're rewrite looks fine.
 
Is your module active? - check if you see it in *System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable module output*  

Is there any other module that extends the same block? - you can enable template path hints & block names hints from *System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug* (or put a `Mage::log(get_class($this))` in product 's view.phtml template)

Comment: Also as I see you don't have a closing tag for `global` node.

Comment: The global error was a typo, thanks for the Mage::log(get_class($this)), that fixed it. The problem was that another plugin extended Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View already. It was an old Yoast_MetaRobots plugin, which is deprecated. I disabled it and everything was fixed. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global error was a typo, solved by using `Mage::log(get_class($this))`, that fixed it. The problem was that another plugin extended Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View already. It was an old Yoast_MetaRobots plugin, which is deprecated. I disabled it and everything was fixed. Thanks for the answer!